# Raspberry Pi stuck on Welcome screen after rebooting

Tags: pi-3, boot-issues, overclocking

I was running a stress test (`stress -c 4`) and measuring the temperature and cpu clock frequency. I also edited the config.txt to overclock my Raspberry Pi 3B. I entered `sudo reboot` into the terminal and it was rebooting, but then it got stuck on the following screen:

[image: Raspberry Pi stuck on this screen]

What could be the cause of this error? How can I appropriately reboot my Raspberry Pi?

EDIT: After shutdown in accordance with @E_Angel's answer, I got a new error:

[image: AAAHH!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by editing the config.txt file to undo the overclocking. In particular the arm_freq was changed to its original value of 700 MHz. I will ask another question on whether or not this means my RPi3B is not overclockable.

Answer (score 0):

To appropriately reboot pi(Linux ) you can use combination key similar to windows , but made for linux :

Shutdown

```
alt + print screen + O
```

Reboot

```
alt + print screen + B
```

Sync discs

```
alt + print screen + S
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about the error above? will it fix that?

Comment: Are you not yet able to properly reboot with combination keys ?

Comment: Lol it's worse. The Raspberry Pi gave the following error when I shutdown and started up the Raspberry Pi again: "unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 17e6e00e"

Comment: Googling gave some similar situations but with different addresses . Do you have some media attached to usb ?!

Comment: Yes, a keyboard.

Comment: So worth to boot with keyboard disconnected to check .

Comment: Did not work...

Comment: I suppose doing a stress test on your RPi was expected get close errors and unexpected situations . If you have no better choice then it is better reinstall operating system .

Answer (score 0):

in **boot/config.txt** string
**hdmi_force_hotplug=1** change on **#hdmi_force_hotplug=1**